# Timed Content Container Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey guys I want to display a container after some time. Consequently I added the following Code:

CSS:

```
.timedcontent1 {
display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){ $(".timedcontent1").fadeIn(500); }, 209000);        
});
```

That worked great! However I inserted an counter created with an external Plugin via shortcode into this container and it isn't displayed, when the container appears. However the author of the plugin advised to use the following CSS Code instead:

```
.timedcontent1 {
   height:0;
   overflow:hidden;
   }
```

However what JS Code do I have to use then? Any ideas?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the DOM to see if the timer actually gets inserted into your `.timecontent1` div??

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your case, you need this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $(".timedcontent1").css("overflow","auto"); 
   }, 209000);
});
```

Comment: I just tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work :/ The container isn'n displayed after the time of 209000 ms

Answer (score 0):

you made height to 0. Make it to it's real size

$(".timedcontent1").css("height","15px"); //15 or any number